# Split omitting the text before

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I'm trying to go through a string:

```
str = "foo chapter 1 bar v1 baz v2 qux chapter 2 quux v1"
```

and find chapter numbers and verse numbers, e.g. (`"chapter 1 foo v1"`). When I find a verse number, I want to add the text:

```
"id=\"(current chapter number)_(current verse number)\""
```

My expected output is:

```
"foo chapter 1 bar id=\"chapter_1_v1\" baz id=\"chapter_1_v2\" qux chapter 2 quux id=\"chapter_2_v1\""
```

Using `split` removes whatever text that doesn't have the specified text to split on. This is my code:

```
str.split(/(?=chapter \d+)/).each do |c|
  c.scan(/(chapter) (\d+)/) {|chap, num| puts c.gsub(/(v\d+)/, 'id="' + chap.to_s + '_' + num.to_s + '_\1"')}
end
```

How do I keep the text before the split? or what is a better way of achieving this result?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `split` is the wrong method to use for this. Reduce your input data to the bare minimum that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at Ruby's [StringScanner](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html) class. It's the building block for a parser to allow you to search for particular tokens such as the next chapter number then the verses.

Comment: It's not necessary to tell us when you've fixed typos or whether you updated the question. We can see the revision history that tells us who did it, what was done and when it was updated.

Comment: ok thanks @theTinMan , I'll check out StringScanner

Comment: What is the logic for getting `"chapter_2_v2"`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, are you asking why I'm changing the verse numbers to "id..."?

Comment: No. I'm not sure what you mean. Where do those numbers come from?

Comment: sorry that was my bad it was meant to be "v1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of splitting, you could use [gsub!()](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) to directly replace the text for every match. And there's a catch, if it matches `chapter \d+`, simply store the value and don't do a replace (replace with the whole match).

I'll use the following regex to either match a chapter or a verse:

```
/\bchapter (\d+)|\b(v\d+)\b/
```

---

**Code:**

```
c = "foo chapter 1 bar v1 baz v2 qux chapter 2 quux v1"
current_chapter = "1"

c.gsub!(/\bchapter (\d+)|\b(v\d+)\b/) { |match| 
        if ($1)
            current_chapter = $1
            match
        else
            "id=\"chapter_" + current_chapter + "_#$2\""
        end
    }

puts c
```

**Output:**

```
foo chapter 1 bar id="chapter_1_v1" baz id="chapter_1_v2" qux chapter 2 quux id="chapter_2_v1"
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ZBU68711)

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I never code in Ruby, so please consider the logic I used, knowing the script more than probably should be improved. -All edits are more than welcome!</sub>

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks so much. I didn't realise you could refer back to the parenthesis in the RegEx throughout the code